# MongoDB findAndModify Optimization

Tags: mongodb, optimization

Currently we write a lot of records into MongoDB, while doing `findAndModify` in another process (basically we want an atomic update on one field of the record when we are querying). The problem is, `findAndModify` seems to slow at 30 ops/sec, that's not acceptable for our request, is there any good way to optimize it?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please specify the full query that you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you could post your exact query that would help, but I suspect that you are not currently specifying the `fields`

```
fields:{"myLongField":0},
```

Try specifying not to return fields you don't need - remember this is **FIND** and modify
So it fetches a document, as well as modifying it.